# What is the Regular Expression for cucumber data table

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I have a problem finding the correct RE for the number in cucumber data table.

My case is like this:

local_dhcp.feature

```
   Feature:
     Scenario Outline:
     Given I have a valid username plus MAC address
     When the user <user> with <mac> logs on to Sonar
     Then the expected result should be <Expected_Result>

Examples:
    | user | mac         | Expected_Result|
    | mattwwww | 200000000001 | OK |
    | matt | 200000000001 | OK |
```

local_dhcp.rb

```
Given /^I have a valid username plus MAC address$/ do 
  @rad = RadiusClient.new
end

When /^the user "(.*?)" with "(\d+)" logs on to Sonar$/ do |username, mac|
  puts "user: #{username} mac: #{mac}"
  @rad.send(username, mac)
end

Then /^the expected result should be "(.*?)"$/ do |result|
   # table is a Cucumber::Ast::Table
  pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
end
```

cucumber features\test.feature
[image: As we could see on the screenshot, it's catched the user, however, not the mac. I don't know why? As it suggests (\d+) is not working in my case either. Please help.]

My questions are:

1. looking at the screenshot, it says 2 passed, however, how come I see this on the bottom:
   You can implement step definitions for undefined steps with these snippets:
   `When /^the user mattwww with (\d+) logs 
   on to Sonar$/ do |arg1|`
   To me, it looks like the the mac address 200000000001 did not pass in. Or, am I wrong?
2. @rad.send(username, mac) this sentence is not running. I tried this  puts "user: #{username} mac: #{mac}", no values displayed. How come?

Comment: It's not clear what exactly are you asking in your question. Can you edit it and be more specific?

Comment: Hi, I have edited my questions, can you please have a look and see it make more sense or not? Thanks.

Comment: It does, thanks. I've written an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the regular expressions in your step definitions, there are double quotes around the parameters. That's why they don't match the feature steps. All you have to do to fix this is add the quotes to the feature:

```
Feature:
  Scenario Outline:
  Given I have a valid username plus MAC address
  When the user "<user>" with "<mac>" logs on to Sonar
  Then the expected result should be "<Expected_Result>"

Examples:
  | user | mac         | Expected_Result|
  | mattwwww | 200000000001 | OK |
  | matt | 200000000001 | OK |
```

or remove them from regular expressions:

```
/^I have a valid username plus MAC address$/
/^the user (.*?) with (\d+) logs on to Sonar$/
/^the expected result should be (.*?)$/
```

Comment: Hi Mechaniclfish, I did realize that, and I have tried whatever you said remove or add double quotes, however, still same result like the screenshot. It still says 2 undefined--- I have skipped the last step where the expected result is.

Comment: Just tested it and it works (https://gist.github.com/deCasale/8000774). Compare what you have with  the gist and check for any typos.

Comment: Removed all of mine. and just copied all yours and ran,--- YES, running successfully! weird. Thanks a lot!

Comment: In the `Then` step, how do I get access to the values of the `user` and `mac` variables as they exist when iterated through as a loop?